# Get Add To cart URL of the first variation of a variable product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor, product-variations

I've been trying to find a way of "quick_add_to_cart" the first variation of any variable product in a product loop. Right now, the URL dynamically redirects to the product single page, which is not really what I want.

Is there a way of making the URL automatically add the ID of a specific product variation to cart?

I understand so much that the URL should be:

```
?add-to-cart=(product_id+1)&quantity=1
```

Where the product_id+1 should represent the URL of the first variation.

If the main page for a variable product ID is `887`, then the first product variation should be `888`?

I am using Elementor and Crocoblock, but can I add this via a function?

I have been trying to find my way around it for a while now.

I've tried fetching the URL dynamically, but I don't know if I have to find a way of adding it programmatically? I have tried just ChatGPT and googled a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get the product variation add to cart URL programmatically, so in your case the first product variation add to cart URL from a variable product.

1. Using [`WC_Product` `add_to_cart_url()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1921-L1928) method,
2. Using [`WordPress` `add_query_arg()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) with `add-to-cart` query argument key

Now first let's get the first variation of a variable product:

```
$product_id = 887; // Variable Product ID

$product = wc_get_product( $product_id ); // Get the product Object of the variable product

$variations_ids = $product->get_children(); // Get an array of the product variations for this variable product

$fist_variation_id = reset($variations_ids); // Get the first product variation ID

$first_variation = wc_get_product( $fist_variation_id ); // Get the product Object of the product variation
```

Now we have the first product variation ID (and the related product object too) of our variable product.

1. Using `add_to_cart_url()` method on the product object to get our add to cart URL:

   ```
    $add_to_cart_url = $first_variation->add_to_cart_url();
   ```
2. Using `add_query_arg()` *(the "quantity" argument is optional: set at `1` by default in WooCommerce)*

   ```
    $add_to_cart_url = site_url( add_query_arg( array(
        'add-to-cart' => $fist_variation_id,
        'quantity' => 1 // Optional
    ) ) );
   ```

Tested and works.

Comment: That works! But if I wanna dynamically chose a product from
$product_id, so it applies to several different products, like in a loop grid, how would I do this?

Comment: @ChristofferForstén Sorry, but you need to ask a new question for that, trying to be explicit, clear, providing your code attempt and explanations.